# Why doesn't this Lua pattern work?

Tags: lua, quotes, lua-patterns

```
local querycreate = "create user 'dddqwd123_dwqd'@'localhost'"
local create, usercreate, username, userhost = querycreate:match("^(%w+)%s+(%w+)%s+\'(%w)\'@\'(%w)\'$")
print(string.format("query: %s", querycreate))
print(string.format(" var create = %s \n var usercreate = %s \n var username = %s \n var userhost = %s", create, usercreate, username, userhost))

query: create user 'dddqwd123_dwqd'@'localhost'
var create = nil
var usercreate = nil
var username = nil
var userhost = nil
```

My regex works fine on http://regexr.com?37voi.

If I change it to `("^(%w+)%s+(%w+)%s+")`, it outputs:

```
var create = create
var usercreate = user
var username = nil
var userhost = nil
```

If I remove quotes from `querycreate` by setting it to `"create user dddqwd123_dwqd @ localhost"` and use `^(%w+)%s+(%w+)%s+(%w+) @ (%w+)$`, then the output is normal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your initial pattern:

```
"^(%w+)%s+(%w+)%s+\'(%w)\'@\'(%w)\'$"
```

- The last two captures in your pattern lack <kbd>+</kbd> specifiers to indicate that they are to read 1 or more characters.
- <kbd>*_*</kbd> is not a word character matched by `%w`. You will need a character class including <kbd>_</kbd> everywhere you would need to match it.
- The escaping of <kbd>'</kbd> within a <kbd>"</kbd>-quoted string is unnecessary.

---

With some improvement:

```
"^(%w+)%s+(%w+)%s+'([%w_]+)'@'([%w_]+)'$"
```

***Alternatively:*** If you wanted to match *anything* within a set of quotes `'`, you could match against its inverse class:

```
"^(%w+)%s+(%w+)%s+'([^']*)'@'([^']*)'$"
```

`([^']*)` will capture anything (including nothing) that isn't `'`, until the end of the string or a `'` is found.

Answer (score 3):

You are missing the <kbd>+</kbd> on the parts of the pattern that match the user and domain.

You have `"^(%w+)%s+(%w+)%s+\'(%w)\'@\'(%w)\'$"`

You need `"^(%w+)%s+(%w+)%s+'([%w_]+)'@'([%w_]+)'$"` (removed unnecessary single quote escaping and to incorporate @RyanStein's comment about <kbd>_</kbd>).

Comment: There is no need to escape `'`.

Comment: True. I meant to comment on that but got distracted. Thanks @lhf.